# Interview cancelled on the very day, re-scheduled phone interview

Tags: interviewing, vacation, phone

I was supposed to have my final interview with one of the executives today afternoon, and got a call this morning that they have to reschedule the interview because the interviewer has urgent issues.

HR manager wanted to reschedule and to make a phone interview instead, next week.
However, I go on vacation next week to another country with 19 hours of time difference so I said I couldn't make it next week.

I said the week after that will be great, but now I am concerned that delaying a phone interview might not be a good decision. Should I mail them that I can manage to have an interview during my vacation? I don't feel like personal vacation can be a good reason to delay an interview. especially when its just an internship interview.

Comment: With a 5h time difference, scheduling a mutually convenient time shouldn't be that difficult. I am not saying that you should do the interview, just that I don't see the relevance of the time difference.

Comment: Agreed with @MaskedMan that the time difference shouldn't be an issue. A bigger problem would be if you have to make an international call, but that could be solved by switching to Skype or some other internet-based communication.

Comment: A final interview with the CEO is over the phone - that sounds a bit fishy if your senior enough to have an interview with the CEO I would expect a FTF

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think companies understand that people go on vacations, and are generally flexible, especially if they had to reschedule in the first place. If you are willing to do the interview on your vacation, then you could say something like:

> Next week I'll be heading on vacation in a drastically different time zone. I can make it work if need be, but would it be possible before then?

I regularly interview interns, and wouldn't take it as a sign that someone doesn't want the job if (s)he needed to reschedule an interview, and I don't think it's abnormal in my industry (software).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the job why would you delay that interview? With 19h time difference you should be able to find a time which is convenient for everybody.

I would call them to arrange a day and time. That is pro-active and it's a lot easier to find a good day/time instead of maybe a few emails back and forth.

Maybe tell them that you are on a vacation so that they know your situation.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see the question here. Want job = do interview. Don't = don't.